# Is it possible to pass Chromcast connection info between Activities?

Tags: android, chromecast

I am developing an app that connects to a Chromecast, everything works fine when I do it from one activity, the problem is, that I want that activity to be fullscreen with no action bar, and no soft buttons. I am achiving that, hiding them when the users connects to the Chromecast, but it would be better if the users connect from the first activity (with action bar) and then goes to the second activity and the magic occurs there. But I can't pass the session between the activities. I have follow [this](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android) tutorial to  make the communication with the chromecast but tried to change a little to make the 2 acitivites communication.

Of course I have tested it and it returns a `NullPointerException`.

**ConnectionFailedListener.java**

```
public class ConnectionFailedListener  implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private String TAG;
private MyConnectionCallbacks myConnectionCB;

public ConnectionFailedListener(String _TAG)
{
    this.TAG=_TAG;
}
private void setMyConnectionCallBack(MyConnectionCallbacks _ConnectionCallbacks)
{
    this.myConnectionCB = _ConnectionCallbacks;
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed ");
    myConnectionCB.teardown();
}
}
```

**Channel.java**

```
public class EventChannel implements Cast.MessageReceivedCallback
{
    private Context myContext;
    private String TAG;
    /**
     * @return custom namespace
     */
    public EventChannel(Context _context, String _TAG)
    {
        this.myContext = _context;
        this.TAG = _TAG;
    }
    public String getNamespace()

    {
        return  myContext.getString(R.string.namespace);
    }

    /*
     * Receive message from the receiver app
     */

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(CastDevice castDevice, String namespace,String message)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + message);
    }

}
```

**ConnectionCallbacks.java**

```
public class MyConnectionCallbacks implements   GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
{
    private String TAG;
    private Context myContext;
    public CastDevice mSelectedDevice;
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private boolean mWaitingForReconnect;
    private EventChannel mEventChannel;
    private String mSessionId;
    private boolean mApplicationStarted;
    private EventChannel myChannel;

    public MyConnectionCallbacks(Context _context, String _TAG)
    {
        this.myContext=_context;
        this.TAG = _TAG;
    }
    public void setApiClient(GoogleApiClient _newApiClient)
    {
        this.mApiClient = _newApiClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
        if (mApiClient == null)
        {
            // We got disconnected while this runnable was pending execution.
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (mWaitingForReconnect)
            {
                mWaitingForReconnect = false;
                // Check if the receiver app is still running
                if ((connectionHint != null) && connectionHint.getBoolean(Cast.EXTRA_APP_NO_LONGER_RUNNING))
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "App  is no longer running");
                    teardown();
                }
                else
                {// Re-create the custom message channel
                    try
                    {
                        Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(mApiClient,mEventChannel.getNamespace(),mEventChannel);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while creating channel", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {// Launch the receiver app because is connected
                Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient,myContext.getString(R.string.app_id), false).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
                                Status status = result.getStatus();
                                Log.d(TAG,"ApplicationConnectionResultCallback.onResult: statusCode"+ status.getStatusCode());
                                if (status.isSuccess())
                                {
                                    ApplicationMetadata applicationMetadata = result.getApplicationMetadata();
                                    mSessionId = result.getSessionId();
                                    String applicationStatus = result.getApplicationStatus();
                                    boolean wasLaunched = result.getWasLaunched();

                                    Log.d(TAG,"application name: "+ applicationMetadata.getName()
                                            + ", status: "+ applicationStatus
                                            + ", sessionId: "+ mSessionId
                                            + ", wasLaunched: "+ wasLaunched);
                                    mApplicationStarted = true;
                                    // Create the custom message channel
                                    mEventChannel = new EventChannel(myContext,TAG);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(mApiClient,mEventChannel.getNamespace(),mEventChannel);
                                    }
                                    catch (IOException e)
                                    {
                                        Log.e(TAG,"Exception while creating channel",e);
                                    }
                                    // set the initial instructions on the receiver
                                    sendMessage("starting from mobile");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.e(TAG,"application could not launch");
                                    teardown();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to launch application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
        mWaitingForReconnect = true;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        if (mApiClient != null && mEventChannel != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient,mEventChannel.getNamespace(), message)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status result)
                            {
                                if (!result.isSuccess())
                                {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Sending message failed");
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception while sending message", e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(myContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void teardown()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "teardown");
        if (mApiClient != null)
        {
            if (mApplicationStarted)
            {
                if (mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Cast.CastApi.stopApplication(mApiClient, mSessionId);
                        if (myChannel != null)
                        {
                            Cast.CastApi.removeMessageReceivedCallbacks(mApiClient,myChannel.getNamespace());
                            myChannel = null;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while removing channel", e);
                    }
                    mApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                mApplicationStarted = false;
            }
            mApiClient = null;
        }
        mSelectedDevice = null;
        mWaitingForReconnect = false;
        mSessionId = null;
    }
}
```

**MediaRouterCallback.java**

```
public class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private Cast.Listener mCastListener;
    private Context myContext;
    private ConnectionFailedListener mConnectionFailedListener;
    public MyConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks;

    public String TAG;
    //private String mSessionId;

    public MyMediaRouterCallback(Context _context, String _TAG)
    {
        this.myContext = _context;
        this.TAG = _TAG;
        mConnectionCallbacks = new MyConnectionCallbacks(myContext,TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected");

        mConnectionCallbacks.mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());
        launchReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteUnselected: info=" + info);
        mConnectionCallbacks.teardown();
        mConnectionCallbacks.mSelectedDevice = null;
    }

    private void launchReceiver()
    {
        try
        {
            mCastListener = new Cast.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "application has stopped");
                    mConnectionCallbacks.teardown();
                }
            };
            //Constructors for Google Play Services Connection
            //mConnectionCallbacks = new MyConnectionCallbacks(myContext,TAG);
            mConnectionFailedListener = new ConnectionFailedListener(TAG);
            Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder =
            Cast.CastOptions.builder(mConnectionCallbacks.mSelectedDevice, mCastListener);
            // ApiClient to Connect to Google Play services
            mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(myContext)
                    .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener)
                    .build();
            mConnectionCallbacks.setApiClient(mApiClient);//setting ApiClient to achieve sendMessage
            //Connect to Google Play services
            mApiClient.connect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed launchReceiver", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstActivity** (where the chromecast is connected)

```
public class ConnectCastActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = ConnectCastActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
    private MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
    private MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_cast);

        // Configure Cast device discovery
        mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getResources().getString(R.string.app_id))).build();
        mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback(getApplicationContext(),TAG);

        TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_helloworld);
        myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Start media router discovery
        mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // End media router discovery
        Log.w(TAG, "onStop");
        //mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy");
//        mMediaRouterCallback.onRouteUnselected(mMediaRouter,null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_connect_cast, menu);
        MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
        // Set the MediaRouteActionProvider selector for device discovery.
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**SecondActivity** (the one that will send the message)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MediaRouter mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        mConnectionCallbacks = new MyConnectionCallbacks(getApplicationContext(),TAG);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //What should I put here?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application with multiple activities, you are better off if you do not tie the cast connectivity and related states to any of those activities, instead you can have a singleton, or use your Application instance or use a background service or ... to maintain the connection and access the required pieces that are maintained in that global place. If it fits your requirement, you might want to use the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) that already does most of the routine stuff for you; if not, you can take a look at it and the see how the [CastVideos](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) sample app uses that and try to do something similar for your application.

Comment: I will take a look at it and let you know